# Finding probability of getting bingo after n amount of balls drawn?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, gambling

At my local bingo hall, there are several ways to get bingo, including the traditional methods. I will use this card as an example for the patterns:
[image: Bingo card]
Along with the column (5 possible drawn from 5 balls, 1 possible from 4), diagonal (2 possible with 4 balls drawn), and row (5 possible from 5 balls, 1 possible from 4), there are a few more.

- Postage stamp: 4 numbers in the corner, e.g. B2, B15, I21, I30 - this can be done in all corners.
- 4 corners: All 4 numbers in the corners - B2, B10, O66, O63.
- 4 edges: All 4 numbers on the middle of each outer column/row - B5, N32, N45, O74.
- Small 4 corners: All numbers on the corners of the inner ring surrounding the Free Space - I30, I16, G52, G58
- Small 4 edges: All numbers on the middle of each column/row surrounding the Free Space - I29, N44, N33, G48

How would you go about calculating all the probabilities of all these after $n$ amount of balls are drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that a ball can only be drawn once. Let's say the game is played on a $N\times N$ board. Let one kind of bingo (say, a column-bingo) be given as having $k$ balls in a specific position.

First draw $n$ balls and place them randomly. The question now is "what is the probability that $k$ of them have ended up in the $k$ specified positions?" There are $\binom{N^{2}-1}{n}$ possible configurations in total, of which $\binom{N^{2}-1}{n-k}$ results in bingo (you place the $k$ balls that gets you the bingo first and then count how many ways there are of distributing the rest of the $n-k$ balls), so the answer is 
$$\frac{\binom{N^{2}-1}{n-k}}{\binom{N^{2}-1}{n}}.$$

If you want the total probability for bingo multiply result this by the total number of different ways of achieving bingo.

Comment: Thank you, but not all cases include 4 draws, I just listed the extras, sorry about that. I also want the probability for the normal bingo, such as in a row or a column where more often than not it requires 5 balls to be drawn (not using the free space, of course)

Comment: @智障的人 If the bingo requires some other number than $4$ specific draws, just place that number instead of the $4$ in the result given.

Comment: So the total probability would be $12(\frac{\binom{25}{n-4}}{\binom{25}{n}})+12(\frac{\binom{25}{n-5}}{\binom{25}{n}})$?

Comment: @智障的人 Yes, if there is $12$ ways of getting bingo with $4$ balls and likewise with $5$. I've generalized my answer, see above.

Comment: Okay, thank you - If you can, can you explain how to do this: You have $x$ amount of bingo cards -  How would you find the probability of bingo combined on each card for $n$ amount of balls drawn?

Comment: @智障的人 Hmm, now that I think about it, I believe we are overcounting. We could, for instance, have a bingo of $4$ being also a bingo of $5$. Let me think about it for a sec.

Comment: By the way, I assume these are $nPr$ functions, correct?

Comment: @智障的人 No, they are ${}_nC_r$ functions, as order doesn't matter. As for your additional question (with multiple cards), I think it would be better to ask that in a separate question, which I would be happy to try to answer, if I have the time.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981598

Comment: In fact, I forgot, if it is $N \times N$, it is not $N^{2}$, it is $N^{2}-1$

Comment: @智障的人 Why? Because of the "free"-square. I don't know what that is.

Comment: @智障的人 Is it because of the "free"-square? Please answer, otherwise I'll retract the edit. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's the free square - sorry about the slow reply

Comment: @智障的人 All right, thanks.